# Facebook hash key not working

Tags: android, facebook, hash, authentication, key

So using the keytool command I was able to generate a hash key for my Android app which uses Facebook login. For purposes of this question, the hash the keytool outputted was "abcdefg=". But when I try to sign on to Facebook from my app, the error says "Key hash abcdefg does not match any stored key hashes" and shows the same exact key I got from keytool just without the equal sign at the end. Why is it not working? Also, when I try to manually type in the key hash on my Facebook developer console (instead of copy/paste), it won't take the key without the equals sign because it only takes keys whose character count is divisible by 4 (my key with equals sign has 28 chars, the key without has only 27 chars). Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
updateLanguage(getApplicationContext(), "en"); 
printHashKey(getApplicationContext(),"ur application package name here");
```

Note1:  Create apk file with release keystore.then run on device the keyhash will print logcat. copy the keyhash and place it on facebook app edit setting page.

Note2: correct keyhash generate only on device. dont use simulator for getting keyhash.

```
  public static String printHashKey(Context context, String packagename)
        {

            String TAG = packagename;
            try
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "keyHash: start");
                PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(TAG,PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature: info.signatures)
                {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    String keyHash = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Log.d(TAG, "keyHash: " + keyHash);
                    return keyHash;
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "keyHash: end");
            }
            catch (NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "keyHash: name:"+e);
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "keyHash: name:"+e);
            }

            return "error";
        }

        public static void updateLanguage(Context context, String code)
        {
            Locale locale = new Locale(code);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
```

Comment: I've found a temporary solution to my problem. It seems that uninstalling the Facebook app on my devices allows my key hash to be accepted. Question is, will signing in to Facebook on my app not work for a user who has Facebook already on their device?

Comment: Uninstalling the FB app DOES NOT allow your key hash to be accepted, it just doesn't send the key hash, and uses a different login mechanism (not SSO), so you get a different type of access token. You app WILL break for other users if they do have the FB app installed. You should generate the key hash appropriately, and include them in your app settings.